# Akeneo - Cannot access specific parts of the backend (http 500)

Tags: symfony, pim, akeneo

I am having some trouble to test `akeneo` (PIM based on symfony) features, as some parts of `akeneo` backend return the following error:

> Sorry, page was not loaded correctly

It specifically occurs if I click under enrich, or settings.

I checked under app/logs, here is what I found:

> [2016-11-05 13:57:36] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("There are no activated locales") in "/var/www/html/pim-community-standard/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Pim/Bundle/EnrichBundle/Resources/views/Attribute/index.html.twig" at line 68." at /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 5700 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Runtime(code: 0): An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template (\"There are no activated locales\") in \"/var/www/html/pim-community-standard/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Pim/Bundle/EnrichBundle/Resources/views/Attribute/index.html.twig\" at line 68. at /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/app/cache/prod/classes.php:5700, LogicException(code: 0): There are no activated locales at /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Pim/Bundle/UserBundle/Context/UserContext.php:110)"} []

I searched almost everything I could find in forums, but I'm still stuck with this issue.

Another error is also logged (depending on where I click):

> [2016-11-05 13:58:55] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "There are no activated locales" at /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Pim/Bundle/UserBundle/Context/UserContext.php line 110 {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): There are no activated locales at /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Pim/Bundle/UserBundle/Context/UserContext.php:110)"} []

These are the two errors that I was able to find in logs.
I double checked the install & all requirements (ubuntu 1.14). Everything seems fine.

Would you have an idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, how did you installed Akeneo ? Did you follow the install documentation ? Are all akeneo's requirements installed ?

Comment: Hello, yes I sticked to their documentations ("install CE from archives" & "system requirements on ubuntu 1.14"). I double checked and everything seems correctly configured based on their tutorial.

Comment: The issue you are having is with active locales. Go to : Settings > Locales and activate a local such as en_US. You will probably also need to activate a currency. Normally the install should have done this. In pim_parameters.yml for installer_data: what do you have ? Did you create a custom installation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to go    "My Account - Additional" and select 2 locales, English and Spanish for example. Then go to console and delete the folder 
    pim-community-standard/app/cache/

When starting again Akeneo, view all akeneo_pim logs, or make a 
      tail -f /logs* 
in the logsfolder.